# Shading / UVs panel not present

Tags: interface, normals, versions

I found a few answers to a question I had (regarding normals) that reference this panel 'Shading / UVs':

[image: Shading Panel]

I do not have this panel **in either object or edit mode**. I have Blender 2.8 and my interface looks like this (in edit mode). How do I show this panel in Blender 2.8?

[image: Blender 2.8]

Comment: As a side comment I see a lot of Blender answers that reference things that do not appear to be there, maybe they are assuming some base knowledge I do not have. Providing more context would be really helpful generally to make it useful for a wider audience (including beginners)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the 2.8 version, the interface has changed, now you can find all the normal functions in the header menu > *Mesh > Normals* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

To see the faces orientation, open the *Viewport Overlays* panel and enable *Face Orientation*, the faces of the objects will appear blue or red, depending on their orientation:

[image]

Comment: Accepted this answer because not only does it demonstrate how to flip normals, it also shows how to see the face orientation and explains that the interface changed from 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Flip and recalculate you can get here:

[image]